# align image and text in <div> tag on the same top line

Tags: css, image, html, alignment

I'm trying to place an image and some text next to the image both of which are vertically aligned at the top. This is the code i'm using but it doesnt seem to be working. It aligns the text at the bottom

```
<img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Desktop.png" alt="" style="float:left; margin-right:5px;" />
<div class="box"><a href="#" target="_blank">Click here to take an online demo</a></div>
```

And 'box' looks like this in the stylesheet,

```
.box {
/* border: 0px solid; */
overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is what it looks like now
[image: what it currently looks like]

Can you suggest the relevant changes needed to make it look like this
[image: what I want it to look like]

Comment: Did you actually add the `vertical-align:top`? That [may, or may not](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html), work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N43Ur/ modify this to reflect your issue, add relevant code

Answer (score 2):

use vertical-align:top  to .box css (or) margin-top

example css

```
             .box {
         /* border: 0px solid; */
             overflow: hidden;
             margin-top:-5px;

                  }
```

Comment: it is of courtesy to accept the answer, case you find it useful.